# Put the Navbar fixed while move between tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, interface

I use the same NavBar in all the views of TabBar, right now I have an Initial TabBarController with five NavigationController and each one with its ViewController.
The thing is that when selecting any section in the TabBar the hole screen, including the NavBar, moves to the selected section.

I need the Navbar and Tabbar to be fixed and only the content in the middle to move when tap to go to some screen.

Hope the description of the problem is clear.
Any ideas what i can do to replicate that behavior?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason that is happening is because each tab/view has it's own NavigationController. Instead you need to share one NavigationController with all of the views so that the NavBar isn't a new one every single time

Answer (score 0):

- Navigation bar is a part of the navigation controller's view. If you have separate navigation controllers, you essentially have those many navigation bars.
- If you just want a single navigation bar / controller and control the content with a bottom bar, you can simply use a toolbar / tabbar (without tabbarcontroller) at the bottom, to navigate / change content